# Mid-to-long-term storage options in Israel

Tags: shipping, israel

Suppose I ship some personal belongings - say, 3-4 m^3 - by sea to Israel, but I don't yet have an apartment to ship them to.

Are there storage spaces I could rent at a reasonably low price, on a weekly or monthly basis, for a period of time which may be as long as several months - and to which I could have my stuff shipped?

If there are - do you have to have someone there to accept the shipped items, or can they just put them in storage for you?

Notes:

- The shipped items will probably be [palletized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pallet), and will not have odd dimensions.
- I don't mind the exact location of storage: Near one of the ports is fine, in Gush Dan or in Haifa is fine, any place that's accessible and not weird.

Answer (score 1):

An example provider of such a service:

A company named [Avia](https://www.avia2000.co.il) offers mid/long-term storage services in compartments/storage rooms of different sizes. They currently have branches in Haifa, Netanya, Rishon Le-Tzion, Petach-Tikva, Holon, Tzur Igal and Kibbutz Har'el.

Their [price quote service](https://www.avia2000.co.il/quotation/) for 5 m^3 of cardboard boxes is in the range of 170-270 NIS per 30 days, depending on which branch you choose. Access to their facilities requires an initial identification, and later on it's based either on a token or a face recognition, and a code you tap in.

Some other companies also offer similar services:

- [Ga'ash Logistics](http://www.gaash-logistica.co.il/ty/) (near Jerusalem)
- [Isra-Storage](https://israstorage.co.il/he/about/) (Ceasaria) - they focus more on pickup+storage+return, but can also do just-storage.
- [Safe Storage - Ichsun Batuach](https://www.ichsunbatuach.co.il/%d7%9e%d7%97%d7%a1%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%94%d7%a9%d7%9b%d7%a8%d7%94/) (Rishon Le-Tzion)

and there are probably others - if you know Hebrew you could search for some in the ["Yellow Pages" directory](https://www.d.co.il) or just on a search engine.

**Caveat**: I have not had any business with any of these companies and cannot vouch for their service. I just found them online.

Comment: I represent "israstorage.co.il (Caesaria) - they focus more on pickup+storage+return, but can also do just-storage"

Answer (score 0):

there is several companies that perform that kind of business in israel,
you can try looking here -
[https://www.b144.co.il/מחסנים-ושירותי-אחסנה/](https://www.b144.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94/)

Comment: Answers on StackExchange website need to have the information in the answer body rather than available via link only. Also, the link you provided is overly broad, and most items at the link do not, according to their name or byline, offer the service I had asked about.